# Magento - Product Configurable As In www.victoriassecret.com

Tags: magento

I am looking for solution or extension for my Magento store.

I need a feature that customer could add product with different product type more than one time.

victoriassecret.com has it and it is really cool feature.

It is named "Add More at a Time"
For ex: http://www.victoriassecret.com/panties/5-for-26-styles/thong-panty-allover-lace-from-cotton-lingerie?ProductID=187902&CatalogueType=OLS

I tried to create  Grouped, Configurable, Bundle in magento but it doesnt work the same.

Please could somebody to help ? :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting the logic which came in my mind.

I think you need to do customization in product details page. You need to fetch all configurable options like Color size , which will match the sku.

suppose , you have one product called , "thong-panty-allover-lace-from-cotton-lingerie".

If you have three colors , you need to add three products,

```
thong-panty-allover-lace-from-cotton-lingerie-blue
thong-panty-allover-lace-from-cotton-lingerie-red
thong-panty-allover-lace-from-cotton-lingerie-green
```

You have to do coding and logically and need to find sku like "thong-panty-allover-lace-from-cotton-lingerie".

Your customized code will be something like this

```
 <?php
    if($_REQUEST['CatalogType']=="OLS"){

    ....

    ...
    $sku = "some value";
   fetch sku of product id " 187902 "and fetch other products which SKU is like $sku.

    After this , in loop , create HTML and SIZE and Color dropdown of each product.
    and on add button , add that product in cart separately.*/
    }
    ?>
```

Hope this will helpful for you.
I have just shared my thought , how you can proceed further , from my point of view.